# fetching only latest data in mysql for each record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table schema like this

1. User(int)
2. created(datetime)
3. metadata

and there are multiple entries in the table for a single user id.

i want to fetch only those data for every user for which created is maximum or latest.

i tried many query but its not working. they are fetching oldest data.
i tried these queries

```
  select user, metadata, max(created) 
  from event_visitor 
  group by user 
  order by max(created)
```

and

```
  SELECT ev1.user, ev1.metadata, ev1.created 
  from event_visitor ev1 
       inner join event_visitor ev2 
       on ev1.user=ev2.user 
  where ev1.created > ev2.created 
  group by user
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `not exists` to only select the latest row for each user by verifying that a 'later' record for a given user does not exists

i.e.

```
select user, metadata, created
from event_visitor ev
where not exists (
    select 1 from event_visitor ev2
    where ev2.user = ev.user
    and ev2.created > ev.created
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (
         SELECT * FROM event_visitor 
         ORDER BY created DESC
   ) u 
GROUP By user
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8e26/7)

Comment: This may return wrong results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html: The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.